# Multiply Function Results in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm still beginner in PHP. I have a small problem, I would to multiply the value `get_formatted_order_total();` with 3.75 and what I did is

```
get_formatted_order_total(); * 3.75
```

but It didn't work.

here is the code

```
<li class="total">
    <?php _e('Total:', 'woocommerce'); ?>
    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
</li>
```

Thank You

Comment: `get_formatted_order_total(); * 3.75` - are you sure `;` is needed?

Comment: **Big Warning: Do not use PHP floats to calculate prices.** That variable type has not been designed for commercial calculations.

Comment: Word of advice, saying "but It didn't work." without posting an explanation as to why, or any relevant error messages/stack traces isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semi-colons go at the [end of an instruction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php). Since this is all one instruction, you need to move the semi-colon to the end of the line:

```
echo get_formatted_order_total() * 3.75;
```

Example: http://codepad.org/HH3RLZCR

Comment: Thank You so match guys! it's working! :D  but the value is wrong it give me 7.5 and it should be 37.5 because the vaule for get_formatted_order_total = 10 [ as you know the vaule is changing all the time not allways 10]

Comment: @user1448371 Don't pay too much attention to the value returned in the example, it's merely to demonstrate the functionality.

Comment: Thanks mate! so much, but the output is 0 , I think this is because the the symbol "$" which included in  get_formatted_order_total() is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: @user1448371 You should remove the `$` from the output and only add it when you're displaying the value. Is that an option? If not, we can solve this another way.

Comment: no unfortunately! is't not an option! I have to multiply 3.75 with "$+numbers"

Comment: @user1448371 No problem. Is `numbers` only made up of actual numbers, or does it have commas and periods?

Comment: Thank You. it looks like this 42.99$ with

Comment: Your amazing!! so glad I did learn my first line in PHP with You! Can't thank you enough , Thanks God!

Comment: last question mate! how can I format this link '    <strong><?php echo $order->get_total() * 3.75;?></strong>  
'

Comment: why is a 50k+ member (and moderator at that) answering questions like this ?

Comment: @tereško If this question is below you, don't answer it. The fact is that the OP asked a straight-forward question, provided relevant code, and was patient with those assisting.

Answer (score 2):

Try so

```
echo get_formatted_order_total() * 3.75;
```

Without ; after ().
; should be after 3.75

Comment: Still needs the semi colan after 3.75

Comment: We can use or not ; in last line, but it's not a good practice.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the value for formatted_order_total is included with it "$" with number

Comment: @yAnTar It is definitely good practice to use semi colons on every line. What if you add extra code to the file and forget the semi colon?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `get_formatted_order_total()` returns a string, formatted for display on the website, not a numerical value that you can use for calculation.

The unformatted value is available as a member variable of the Order class, so

```
echo $order->order_total * 3.75;
```

should work.

In order to understand this, look at the [source code of Woocommerce](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/classes/class-wc-order.php#L389): `Order::get_formatted_order_total()` simply formats `Order::order_total` with a helper function `woocommerce_price()`:

```
/** Gets order total - formatted for display */
function get_formatted_order_total() {
    $formatted_total = woocommerce_price( $this->order_total );

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', $formatted_total, $this );
}
```