# multiply a simple php with symbol

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiply Function Results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976133/multiply-function-results-in-php)

I'm still beginner in PHP. I have a small problem, I would to multiply the value `get_formatted_order_total();` with 3.75 and what I did is (which is wrong)

```
get_formatted_order_total(); * 3.75
```

The guys help me out with this code

```
<?php

function get_formatted_order_total() {
    return 2;
}

echo get_formatted_order_total() * 3.75;
```

and it's working just fine! but the problem is that the output is 7.5.

I almost forgot to mention that the value for `formatted_order_total();` is included with it "$" and numbers

here is the code

```
<li class="total">
<?php _e('Total:', 'woocommerce'); ?>
<strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
```

Thank You

Comment: If you're doing `2 * 3.75`, you're unlikely to get anything other than `7.5`...

Comment: the code '<?php

function get_formatted_order_total() {
    return 2;
}

echo get_formatted_order_total() * 3.75;
' is just an example , the problem is  the output is 0 , I think this is because the the symbol "$" which included in get_formatted_order_total().

Comment: So the expected output is `$ 7.5`?

Comment: This question is closely related to WooCommerce, a shop plugin for Wordpress. It is GPL licensed and seems to be quite popular lately. Maybe it would deserve its own tag (I cannot create new ones, though).
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions, update your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976133 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$symbol = substr(get_formatted_order_total(), 0, 1);
$numerics = substr(get_formatted_order_total(), 1);
echo $symbol . ($numerics * 3.75);
```

Comment: You can't concat a number with a string. You also should be converting `$numerics` to a `float` or an `int` before multiplying.

Comment: Urrrm, this is PHP, yes you can.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've encountered issues with this before. Maybe I'm wrong, I'll go and check.

Comment: You'd be right in the instance where I didn't use brackets. But I did :)

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong. I don't know which language I was thinking about, or maybe I just assumed this from my first day with PHP trying to concat using `+` (facepalm). Have an upvote :D

Comment: This will fail as soon as any different formatting is used, like `USD 9.99` or just different whitespace `$  9.99`. Don't even think about Internationalization (`9,99 €`).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I understand your problem.

You're probably actually doing something like this:

```
function get_formatted_order_total() {
    return '$' . 2;
}
echo get_formatted_order_total() * 3.75;
```

This will echo `0`.

The problem is that you are attempting to multiply a string `'$2'` by a number `3.75`. This implicitly requires converting the string to a number.  Strings that do not begin with numbers are converted to the value `0` (see [string conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)). Since your string begins with `$`, it will be converted to `0`, hence why the result of your multiplication is `0`.

You need to do the multiplication before the concatenation.  For example:

```
function get_formatted_order_total($amount) {
    return '$' . (2 * $amount);
}
echo get_formatted_order_total(3.75);
```

Comment: And in general terms: _never ever_ perform calculations on formatted numbers whatsoever. Formatting is the very last act you perform on any number in your application, and generally resides in template-like code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should return the value you are after.

`function get_formatted_order_total($value) 
{`

```
$orderTotal =  2 * $value;

$orderTotal = '$' . $orderTotal;

return $orderTotal;
```

}

Code Usage would be someting like below:

`$orderValue = 3.75;`

```
<strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total($orderValue); ?></strong>
```

This should return what you require.